# How do I install Sigil on Fedora 17?

Tags: installation, fedora, epub, sigil

I want to use Sigil, which isn't in the official repositories. First I added a repository called home_xwaver and installed it from there, but it started throwing errors, unable to save a book. I found [a blog post telling me to change some libraries](http://paolobernardi.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/sigil-on-fedora-14/), but I couldn't find the installation location of sigil. The executable was in /usr/share/bin, but I found no folder containing libraries, it wasn't in the default location of /opt/sigil.

As a second try, I deinstalled the package and tried to download it from its homepage. I downloaded the source and tried to compile it. It turned out to require QT 4.7.0, and the one I have installed is 4.8.2, so it wouldn't compile. I don't know where I can change the required version, and if it will work at all if I compile it with the new QT.

*Edit* some details: Sigil has no configure file. The docu says to run

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release /path/to/extracted/folder
make
sudo make install
```

But the `cmake` line already fails for me. The error is

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_QTWEBKIT_INCLUDE_DIR) (found suitable
  version "4.8.2", required is "4.7.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1172 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/Sigil/CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package)
```

The third thing I tried was a compiled file from the home page. I didn't have high hopes, because it is deprecated. (Currently, there is no non-deprecated Linux installation file on the home page, only Windows and Mac files). It started a graphical installer which hung itself in the middle of installation.

Is it possible to install Sigil on the current Fedora, and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `qtwebkit-devel` package:

```
yum install qtwebkit-devel
```

You may need other -devel packages, but that won't be obvious unless cmake crashes again complaining of something missing.

Answer (score 1):

Installing from source isn't best way on GNU/Linux. If available use always binary or source packages. I hope Sigil will hit official repositories as soon as possible. For now following may help:

- go https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=772362
- download http://people.fedoraproject.org/~jwrdegoede/sigil.spec
- update spec file for 0.5.3 (Just Version line and %changelog section)
- comment out all patch lines
- use **rpmbuild -ba sigil.spec** command
- follow the instructions at cli (copy source archive file to proper path, install dependencies etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on Fedora 17 64-bit:

```
yum install qtwebkit-devel boost-devel
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make
make install
```